# Why don't graphing tools represent holes in a graph?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

Why don't graphing tools represent holes in the graph of a function? A hole at a point in a graph is point where function is not defined. Suppose there is a function

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}-1}$$

Its should be like this

[image: Graph 1]

But online tools and even my android graphing tool app shows graph like this

[image: Graph 2]

What I'm saying is that, apart from a circle, there must be some sort of marks representing that the function is not defined here.

Comment: Such apps can be, of course, misleading. Take care when using them.

Comment: Did you mean
$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}-1}?$$
Your plot doesn't match the function in your post, but it does match this one.

Comment: Ya Sorry I mistyped it. Above I've edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programs/apps don't usually (if ever) show the hole because it is *very* small. It's just one point on the graph. Less than a pixel in size, making it impossible to actually show it on your screen.

Now, as for why these programs don't *indicate* where point-discontinuities are? I don't know. You'd have to talk to the developer of the program. I suppose these apps could implement a way of indicating it to the user. There *are* ways of doing it yourself, but you'd have to symbolically program your own function/method in the language (if the app is actually a programming language).

Answer (score 0):

Looking for gaps in the definition would require symbolic manipulation of the expression. Graphing requires only evaluating the function at a few points